# Not able to display text below icon on button

Tags: android

[image]I want to display text below each image but i am not able to do this how i set this?
through this coding i get my text side by side to my image but i want to display it below image.

how i get text exact below of my icon.

this is my xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2F4F4F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Select Drinks"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgfirst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/beer_cider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_beer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Do stuff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgsecond"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wine_champagne" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtwine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Do stuff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgthird"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/spirits_shots" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_spirits"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Do stuff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgforth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/other" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtother"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Do" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgfifth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/drink_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgsixth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/date_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgseven"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/info_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Set the `orientation` attribute on the `LinearLayout`s to `vertical`.

Comment: how i add screenshot?

Comment: Like Mike suggested, add the line `android:orientation="vertical"` in LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

set orientation to vertical in linear layout in which you are using image and text

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: its working but one problem is there according to my text size,size of button also increases how i set all button of same size with different text.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
remove `imageview` and replace my code by ur `textview`

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/txt_beer"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:text="Do stuff"
   android:drawableTop="@drawable/beer_cider"
   android:drawablePadding="10dp" /> // padding if u want
```

**edit:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2F4F4F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Select Drinks"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_beer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Do stuff"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/beer_cider" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtwine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Do stuff"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/wine_champagne" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_spirits"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Do stuff"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/spirits_shots" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtother"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Do" 
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/other"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgfifth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/drink_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgsixth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/date_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_button_margin_top"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgseven"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/info_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did like this but my problem is that all textview is of different size accorind to image and text how i set all this four button of same size.?

Comment: how i post it i have no idea for this?

Comment: check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: i reffered this but i not able to find insert image option :(

Comment: k set gravity = center n try

Comment: i successfully added screenshot which i want as output please help me to get this type screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2F4F4F"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Select Drinks"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/ty"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfirst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_beer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Do stuff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgsecond"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtwine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Do stuff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgthird"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_spirits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Do stuff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgforth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtother"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Do" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgfifth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgsixth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgseven"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```